# Flutter: Text.rich widget is revers the WidgetSpan if you add arabic text

Tags: flutter, dart, arabic, richtext

[image: the green container is should be in the red and there is in the green.]please can any one help me?
Text.rich widget does not work successfully with arabic text. there are a problem with the text direction.
lets give an example
when i run the app the order of the container in the below code is come reverse
that is a big problem for me

```
Text.rich(
                TextSpan(
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(text: 'بِسۡمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحۡمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ'),
                    WidgetSpan(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        color: Colors.green,child:Text('1'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextSpan(text: 'ٱلۡحَمۡدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلۡعَٰلَمِينَ'),
                    WidgetSpan(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        color: Colors.blue,child:Text('2'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextSpan(text: 'ٱلرَّحۡمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ'),
                    WidgetSpan(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        color: Colors.red,child:Text('3'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              )
```

Comment: Hello Hakim, I tested the code you posted, and the sura was written on the screen properly, can you add an image of the result you get?

Comment: Green then blue then red container. Because we write with arabic so it sould be red then blue then green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the most difficult problems can be solved by very simple things.
There may be many long and difficult ways to solve this problem.

[https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54400#issuecomment-662558160][1]

But the simplest way that i found is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Quran',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Quran Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   List<Widget> wrapList(List m) {
    List<Widget> myList = [];
    for (var i in m) {
      String a = i['text'] as String;
      int b = i['num'];
      List l2 = a.split(' ');
      myList.addAll(List.generate(l2.length, (e) {
        return Text(
          e == l2.length - 1 ? '${l2[e]}' : '${l2[e]} ',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        );
      }));
      myList.add(
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          child: Text("$b"),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return myList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Wrap(
        children: wrapList([
          {'text': 'بِسۡمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحۡمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ', 'num': 1},
          {'text': 'ٱلۡحَمۡدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلۡعَٰلَمِينَ', 'num': 2},
          {'text': 'ٱلرَّحۡمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ', 'num': 3},
          {'text': 'مَٰلِكِ يَوۡمِ ٱلدِّينِ', 'num': 4},
          {'text': 'إِيَّاكَ نَعۡبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسۡتَعِينُ', 'num': 5},
          {'text': 'ٱهۡدِنَا ٱلصِّرَٰطَ ٱلۡمُسۡتَقِيمَ', 'num': 6},
          {
            'text':
                'صِرَٰطَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَنۡعَمۡتَ عَلَيۡهِمۡ غَيۡرِ ٱلۡمَغۡضُوبِ عَلَيۡهِمۡ وَلَا ٱلضَّآلِّينَ',
            'num': 7
          },
        ]),
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are `WidgetSpan`s between `TextSpan`s which ruins the `TextDirection` because `WidgetSpan` does not follow the directionality,
you can replace the `WidgetSpan` with a `TextSpan` and it will work I tested id

```
Text.rich(
    TextSpan(
        children: [
            TextSpan(text: 'بِسۡمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحۡمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ'),
            TextSpan(text: ' 1 ', style: TextStyle(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            )),
            TextSpan(text: 'ٱلۡحَمۡدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلۡعَٰلَمِينَ'),
            TextSpan(text: ' 2 ', style: TextStyle(
               backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            )),
            TextSpan(text: 'ٱلرَّحۡمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ'),
            TextSpan(text: ' 3 ', style: TextStyle(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            )),
        ],
    ),
    style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'UthmanicHafs1'
    ),
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
),
```

Comment: thanks for the information. is there any way to solve this problem i need to use widgetspan

Comment: I would prefer to use a proper font that renders the numbers in Quran style to make it look like a quran page, I will try to make it work with `WidgetSpan` when I get home and I will keep you updated

Comment: I will be grateful.

Comment: I found someone has solved it https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54400#issuecomment-662558160
please tell me if it works for you

Comment: it have an error and can not run. but i solved the problem and answer the question

Answer (score 0):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Widget Test',
      home: TestWidgetSpans(),
    );
  }
}

double _getYOffsetOf(GlobalKey key) {
  final box = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

  return box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dy;
}

double _getXOffsetOf(GlobalKey key) {
  final box = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
  return box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dx;
}

void _resolveSameRow(List<GlobalKey<_WidgetSpanWrapperState>> keys) {
  var middle = (keys.length / 2.0).floor();
  for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++) {
    var a = keys[i];
    var b = keys[keys.length - i - 1];
    var left = _getXOffsetOf(a);
    var right = _getXOffsetOf(b);
    a.currentState!.updateXOffset(right - left);
    b.currentState!.updateXOffset(left - right);
  }
}

class TestWidgetSpans extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestWidgetSpans({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final keys = <GlobalKey<_WidgetSpanWrapperState>>[];
    nextKey() {
      var key = GlobalKey<_WidgetSpanWrapperState>();
      keys.add(key);
      return key;
    }

    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      List<GlobalKey<_WidgetSpanWrapperState>>? sameRow;
      GlobalKey<_WidgetSpanWrapperState> prev = keys.removeAt(0);
      for (var key in keys) {
        if (_getYOffsetOf(key) == _getYOffsetOf(prev)) {
          sameRow ??= [prev];
          sameRow.add(key);
        } else if (sameRow != null) {
          _resolveSameRow(sameRow);
          sameRow = null;
        }
        prev = key;
      }
      if (sameRow != null) {
        _resolveSameRow(sameRow);
      }
    });
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text.rich(
            TextSpan(
              text: 'هذا اختبار',
              style: TextStyle(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
              children: [
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: WidgetSpanWrapper(
                    key: nextKey(),
                    child: const TestWidgetSpan(color: Colors.red, order: 1),
                  ),
                ),
                const TextSpan(text: ' و '),
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: WidgetSpanWrapper(
                    key: nextKey(),
                    child: const TestWidgetSpan(color: Colors.orange, order: 2),
                  ),
                ),
                const TextSpan(text: ' ثم '),
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: WidgetSpanWrapper(
                    key: nextKey(),
                    child: const TestWidgetSpan(color: Colors.yellow, order: 3),
                  ),
                ),
                const TextSpan(text: ' ، لكنه معطل'),
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: WidgetSpanWrapper(
                    key: nextKey(),
                    child: const TestWidgetSpan(color: Colors.green, order: 4),
                  ),
                ),
                const TextSpan(text: ' اختبارات '),
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: WidgetSpanWrapper(
                    key: nextKey(),
                    child: const TestWidgetSpan(color: Colors.blue, order: 5),
                  ),
                ),
                const TextSpan(text: ' اختبارات '),
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: WidgetSpanWrapper(
                    key: nextKey(),
                    child: const TestWidgetSpan(color: Colors.purple, order: 6),
                  ),
                ),
                const TextSpan(text: ' اختبارات '),
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: WidgetSpanWrapper(
                    key: nextKey(),
                    child: const TestWidgetSpan(color: Colors.pink, order: 7),
                  ),
                ),
                const TextSpan(text: ' اختبارات '),
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: WidgetSpanWrapper(
                    key: nextKey(),
                    child: const TestWidgetSpan(color: Colors.lime, order: 8),
                  ),
                ),
                const TextSpan(text: ' اختبارات '),
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: WidgetSpanWrapper(
                    key: nextKey(),
                    child: const TestWidgetSpan(color: Colors.teal, order: 9),
                  ),
                ),
                const TextSpan(text: ' اختبارات '),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetSpanWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const WidgetSpanWrapper({super.key, required this.child});

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<WidgetSpanWrapper> createState() => _WidgetSpanWrapperState();
}

class _WidgetSpanWrapperState extends State<WidgetSpanWrapper> {
  Offset offset = Offset.zero;

  void updateXOffset(double xOffset) {
    setState(() {
      offset = Offset(xOffset, 0);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.translate(
      offset: offset,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class TestWidgetSpan extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final int order;

  const TestWidgetSpan({super.key, required this.color, required this.order});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color.withOpacity(0.5),
      width: 40,
      child: Center(child: Text(order.toString())),
    );
  }
}
```